# Dot product using vectors in java

Tags: java, processing-efficiency, dot-product

I am having a very large matrix of size (20K x 20K) or more. I need to apply dot product for every combination of two rows and list the combination of rows in descending order of the values obtained from dot product. What could be the efficient way to apply the dot product to minimise the time required for execution?

Comment: So you will get like 400 millions of dot products, right? To calculate each of them you need to perform at least 20K multiplications, thus in total you want to calculate 8E+12 multiplications? Are you using `double` type for your matrix elements?

Comment: You just have to do all the multiplications and additions. For example, see public double dot(Vector that) at http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/34nbody/Vector.java.html.  This can be made to run faster by using a parallel algorithm and distributing it over a cluster and could be done  in memory with Apache Spark. Several styles of dot product parallel algorithms are shown in http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~bisse101/Book/PSC/psc1_3.pdf.